# A record DNS for my domain not working

Tags: domain-name-system, web-hosting, dns-hosting

I have problems with my A DNS record. My parent domain is www.altermedia.ba. Last month we  bought new hosting service at Arvixe, and registered our subdomain curiosity.altermedia.ba on their DNS servers. Arvixe sent me ip addresses of DNS servers for our subdomain curiosity.altermedia.ba. So, for my parent domain altermedia.ba I have one DNS servers, and Arvixe DNS servers for my subdomain curiostiy.altermedia.ba. 
In my altermedia.ba DNS servers I added NS records for curiosity.altermedia.ba, which are pointing to my Arvixe DNS server.

In my Arvixe DNS server I added A record for curiosity.altermedia.ba, but when I browse http://curiosity.altermedia.ba, I get DNS resolving error.

When I run DNS lookup for NS record for my curiosity.altermedia.ba domain on following site:
http://www.samdns.com/default.aspx I get following results:

**Domain:** curiosity.altermedia.ba. **Answer:** ns1.cheetah.arvixe.com.
**Domain:**curiosity.altermedia.ba.  **Answer:**ns2.cheetah.arvixe.com.

That is totaly fine, but when I run same test looking for A record of curiosity.altermedia.ba, it's not working and it says that there is no A record.

Where is the problem?

Comment: It looks like you're actively modifying the zone as I'm typing this, so it's hard to help you because the information I have at my disposal keeps changing.

Comment: There currently is an A record. That website is doing some weird redirect to Facebook.

Comment: Currently I'm not changing anything!

Comment: My web site should redirect to facebook, it is OK. But why I can't access it? Chrome tells me it can't find my site?

Comment: Are you on Windows or Unix-based?

Comment: Currently on windows.

Comment: Open a command prompt and type `ipconfig /flushdns` followed by enter, then try Chrome again.

Comment: did it, and nothing

Answer (score 2):

On `dns-srv-01.lol.ba.`, you want these records (in the `altermedia.ba` zone):

```
altermedia.ba.    NS    dns-srv-01.lol.ba.
altermedia.ba.    NS    dns-srv-02.lol.ba.
curiosity.altermedia.ba.    NS    ns1.cheetah.arvixe.com.
curiosity.altermedia.ba.    NS    ns2.cheetah.arvixe.com.
```

On `ns1.cheetah.arvixe.com.`, you want these records (in the `curiosity.altermedia.ba` zone):

```
curiosity.altermedia.ba.    NS    ns1.cheetah.arvixe.com.
curiosity.altermedia.ba.    NS    ns2.cheetah.arvixe.com.
curiosity.altermedia.ba.    A     <ip here>
```

Comment: But in curiosity.altermedia.ba zone, I can't add NS record. Only A, CNAME and TXT

Comment: Maybe those two are setup automatically by the provider? The most important part is the main zone file which should have NS records for the curiosity domain.

Comment: By the way, if you want `curiosity.altermedia.ba` to point to `198.58.85.113`, it's already working.

Comment: It's not working for me: http://pokit.org/get/?3d1323a7b69571b3d24056ebb616dc6b.jpg

Comment: I tried in Chrome also.

Comment: It works perfectly fine for the rest of the world. What happens if you type `nslookup curiosity.altermedia.ba` ?

Comment: http://pokit.org/get/?846ced50e0c07be5bd322153a769d9de.jpg

Comment: Ignoring the obvious spelling mistake, it might be that this server is caching the old record still. I'd wait an hour and give it another go.

Comment: This is when I fix spelling mistake: http://pokit.org/get/?e00967c330166d58bc6473a5b000be65.jpg

Comment: Well, it used to work, but now my nameserver stopped resolving it too. And you're telling me you did absolutely nothing to the zone this whole time?

Comment: I didn't changed anything for 4 hours!

Comment: Can you not get support from your two providers? I'm all for helping you but the troubleshooting makes no sense and this is pretty basic for serverfault

Comment: I will try to contact Arvixe to resolve the problem. Thx for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Name Server (NS ) entry you need to do in  Domain Registrar.

Comment: added, nothing happened!

Comment: Instead of ARVIXE DNS use DNSEXIT its fast and reliable once u create DNS Record with DNSEXIT update name servers with Domain Registrar. 1. ns1.dnsexit.com 2. ns2.dnsexit.com 3. ns3.dnsexit.com 4. ns4.dnsexit.